# .htaccess doesn't work on Ubuntu

Tags: apache2

I installed Ubuntu 10 and apache 2. Now I create an .htaccess file. The file contains:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .jpg
Addhandler application/x-httpd-php .jpg
```

I want to run .jpg files as PHP files. It works on other servers but when I tried it on my server (localhost actually) it doesn't work.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably better for serverfault...

But Make sure that you have.

`AccessFileName .htaccess`

and  that you don't have `AllowOverride None`  set for the directory in which you have your .htaccess file located..